# Python - My while loop not generating random numbers in a function called inside the while loop

Tags: python, function, random, while-loop

I'm trying to get the while loop to randomize a monster stats and its name on a function called inside the loop, it creates it onces but it's not randomieze everytime the while completes a loop.

Everytime I run the `Mobs()` outside the loop, the mobs are randomize, yet somehow it doesn't work on inside the loop.

```
import random
import time

mobs = ['rat', 'snake', 'bat', 'spider', 'mole', 'hawk', 'fox', 'vulture', 'beetle']

mobs_names = random.choice(mobs)
mob_hp = random.randint(45, 60)
mob_damage = random.randint(8, 13)
mob_exp = random.randint(20, 23)

class Mobs:
    def __init__(self, hp=mob_hp, damage=mob_damage, name=mobs_names, exp=mob_exp):

        self.hp = hp
        self.damage = damage
        self.name = name
        self.exp = exp

        print("Monster is a " + self.name.title() + ' and it\'s stats are...')
        print('HP: ' + str(self.hp))
        print('Attack Damage: ' + str(self.damage))

gameloop = True

#spawn_mobs = Mobs()
world_level = 0
battlebegun = print("Battle has started")

while gameloop == True:
    while world_level < 10:
        world_level += 1
        print(world_level)
        if world_level <= 10:
            spawn_mobs = Mobs()
            battlebegun
            time.sleep(1)
            continue

    break #gameloop = False


print("Game over")
```

Comment: You're not calling the `random` functions inside your loop. You only call them before your loop.

Comment: `random.choice` and `random.randint` are where the randomization happens. Currently you only randomize the values once. You need to randomize them again for each loop iteration. So move the lines inside the loop. Also you need to pass the randomized values inside the `Mobs()` initialization like `spawn_mobs = Mobs(mob_hp, mob_damage, mobs_names, mob_exp)`. Otherwise it's still going to be the same every time.

Answer (score 1):

You are only randomizing the values once because they are not being called inside the loop. It's like doing this:

```
random_var = random.randint(1, 10)
while True:
    print(random_var)
```

Output:

```
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5
```

as opposed to this:

```
while True:
    random_var = random.randint(1, 10)
    print(random_var)
```

Output:

```
3, 2, 7, 4, 6, 6, 9
```

In the first example, the random function is called once because it isn't in the while loop, but in the second example it keeps being randomized. Here is your code fixed with the randomization inside the loop.

```
import random
import time

mobs = ['rat', 'snake', 'bat', 'spider', 'mole', 'hawk', 'fox', 'vulture', 'beetle']

# You can still keep this if you want in order to have random initial values.
mobs_names = random.choice(mobs)
mob_hp = random.randint(45, 60)
mob_damage = random.randint(8, 13)
mob_exp = random.randint(20, 23)

class Mobs:
    def __init__(self, hp=mob_hp, damage=mob_damage, name=mobs_names, exp=mob_exp):

        self.hp = hp
        self.damage = damage
        self.name = name
        self.exp = exp

        print("Monster is a " + self.name.title() + ' and it\'s stats are...')
        print('HP: ' + str(self.hp))
        print('Attack Damage: ' + str(self.damage))

gameloop = True

#spawn_mobs = Mobs()
world_level = 0
battlebegun = print("Battle has started")

while gameloop == True:
    while world_level < 10:
        world_level += 1
        print(world_level)
        if world_level <= 10:

            # Randomizes mob values inside loop.
            mobs_names = random.choice(mobs)
            mob_hp = random.randint(45, 60)
            mob_damage = random.randint(8, 13)
            mob_exp = random.randint(20, 23)

            spawn_mobs = Mobs()
            battlebegun
            time.sleep(1)
            continue

    break #gameloop = False


print("Game over")
```